# Getting String output as ... (3 dots)

Tags: java, json, rest

I am trying to consume REST webservice in java application following the example http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

When I try to print the output, it prints '...' (3 dots). What does this mean? How do I get a proper readable String output from my webservice call?

I can see the JSON through my browser:

> {"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":[{"ID":"0","NAME":"abc"},{"ID":"1","NAME":"xyz"}],"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}

Code:

```
    try {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("https://someurl/api/Projects");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("JsonString: " + output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: what does the text of the response look like when you request it via a browser?

Comment: edited my post to show the json

Comment: What do you need your output to be?

Comment: just as I see in the browser

Comment: When you consume your REST Webservice through browser, do you see Response Header `Content-Type` as `application/json`. It doesn't look like your REST webservice is returning valid header for client to consume it right.